# Better method for returning multiple rows using AND Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was just wondering if there was a better way of processing the statement below, as I feel this is quite limited.

```
SELECT Bill_of_Materials.BM_Assembly
    , Bill_of_Materials.BM_Part_No
    , Bill_of_Materials.BM_Qty
    , Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Part_No
    , Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Qty
    , Bill_of_Materials_2.BM_Part_No
    , Bill_of_Materials_2.BM_Qty
    , Stock_File.STK_Description
FROM ((Bill_of_Materials INNER JOIN Bill_of_Materials AS Bill_of_Materials_1 ON Bill_of_Materials.BM_Assembly = Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Assembly) 
    INNER JOIN Stock_File ON Bill_of_Materials.BM_Assembly = Stock_File.STK_Part_No) 
    INNER JOIN Bill_of_Materials AS Bill_of_Materials_2 ON Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Assembly = Bill_of_Materials_2.BM_Assembly
WHERE (((Bill_of_Materials.BM_Part_No)="161070") 
    AND ((Bill_of_Materials.BM_Qty)=2) 
    AND ((Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Part_No)="161317") 
    AND ((Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Qty)=2) 
    AND ((Bill_of_Materials_2.BM_Part_No)="410382"));
```

I am trying to run several `AND` statements on the same field, but I need to return multiple rows. Now depending on how many `AND` statements I want to run depends on how many times I need to join the table, but I really want this to be more dynamic.

I am trying to find a 'Finished Item' by matching several componets which are used in the build (hence the multiple `AND` statements.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I don't understand why you join mutiple time the same table on the same field. Why don't use `WHERE Bill_of_Materials.BM_Part_No IN ("161070","161317",...) AND Bill_of_Materials.BM_Qty=2` or something like `WHERE (Bill_of_Materials.BM_Part_No ="161070" AND Bill_of_Materials.BM_Qty=2 ) OR (Bill_of_Materials.BM_Part_No ="161317" AND Bill_of_Materials.BM_Qty=2)...`

Comment: Because I need to return a finished item which contains all three items, not 1 of 3.

Comment: ok, then what are the "multiple rows" you need to return?

Comment: A finished item may consist of X amount of rows, and they may be more than one finished item which meets the criteria. What I need I need to see if the rows where all components exist in the same finished item, not any finished item with 1 out of 3.

Answer (score 0):

You may simplify the query like this :

```
SELECT Bill_of_Materials.BM_Assembly,
       Bill_of_Materials.BM_Part_No,
       Bill_of_Materials.BM_Qty,
       Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Part_No,
       Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Qty,
       Bill_of_Materials_2.BM_Part_No,
       Bill_of_Materials_2.BM_Qty,
       Stock_File.STK_Description
  FROM Bill_of_Materials
       INNER JOIN Bill_of_Materials AS Bill_of_Materials_1
          ON Bill_of_Materials.BM_Assembly = Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Assembly
             AND Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Part_No = "161317"
             AND Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Qty = 2
       INNER JOIN Bill_of_Materials AS Bill_of_Materials_2
          ON Bill_of_Materials_1.BM_Assembly = Bill_of_Materials_2.BM_Assembly
             AND Bill_of_Materials_2.BM_Part_No = "410382"
       INNER JOIN Stock_File
          ON Bill_of_Materials.BM_Assembly = Stock_File.STK_Part_No
 WHERE Bill_of_Materials.BM_Part_No = "161070"
       AND Bill_of_Materials.BM_Qty = 2;
```

With restritions inside the `join` conditon, you are reducing the numbers of records for each join.